# How to show a greeting message when BOT starts api.ai / dialogflow in App

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

I am creating a BOT in **Dialogflow** on Android.
I want to show a greeting message every time user launches the app. 
How to achieve this ?

Comment: You have to define the default welcome intent. It is predefined like the default fallback intent.

Comment: are you talking about triggering intent via webhooks ? @Wernerson

Comment: Yeah just like every other interaction.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to mention in the default welcome intent or add an event for that particular intent. If you're using Dialogflow with kommunicate then to show different welcome messages on different pages of your website. Please refer to this [doc](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/bot-dialogflow-integration#custom-welcome-messages-from-bots) for info.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a welcome event and when user first time opens the chatbot you have to send just event name in parameter there is no need for the query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is provision to do so in api.ai. The event is a feature that allows you to invoke intents by an event name instead of a user query. You just need to define event names for intents. Then, you can trigger these intents by sending a /query request containing an event parameter. Please read the document here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/events